# Laravel custom action names and route names using a resource controller?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

By default Resource controller gives you those Actions and Route names:

```
ACTION  ROUTE NAME
index   resource.index
create  resource.create
store   resource.store
show    resource.show
edit    resource.edit
update  resource.update
destroy resource.destroy
```

and want to rename both of them (Actions and Routes names) to:

```
ACTION  ROUTE NAME
**browse    resource.browse**
create  resource.create
store   resource.store
show    resource.show
edit    resource.edit
update  resource.update
**delete    resource.delete**
```

And still use a Resource Controllers, like this:

```
Route::resource('resource', 'ResourceController');
```

and not a list of GET routes like this:

```
Route::get('resource', 'ResourceController@index');
Route::get('resource/create', 'ResourceController@index');
...
```

Comment: create your own extended ResourceRegistrar and you can define them how you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a good solution suggested by Laravel doc:

```
Route::resource('resource', 'ResourceController', ['names' => [
    'index' => 'resource.browse',
    'delete' => 'resource.delete',
]]);
```

The rest will have the default names.

Related section in Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-naming-resource-routes

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom routes for the resource controller as well.

```
// for **browse    resource.browse**
Route::post('resource/browse', 'ResourceController@browse')->name('resource.browse');

//for **delete    resource.delete**
Route::delete('resource/delete', 'ResourceController@delete')->name('resource.delete');
```

Comment: I think i need something that will change default configuration. I would like to have a route like this:
Route::resource('resource', 'ResourceController');

and in the controller have the methods browse and delete.
I think Ahmad's solution does exactly that.